# Add Action Listener of Declared Component From Another Class

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Here, I want to register the Action Listener of newBTN , in Class B.

Note :: newBTN  is not added and not initialized. Also, class A is out of my control and cannot be changed.

```
class A {
    private JButton newBTN = null;
}
```

How can I access newBTN of class A, so I can register action listener of newBTN from class B?

```
class B {
}
```

Comment: use a getter method? Also, in Java you have to use `class` instead of `Class`

Comment: In my case, Class A is already exst. I cannot change the code in Class A

Comment: Then you can't. Try extending it, if it is protected, you can.

Comment: @MilanBasnet: Always add that kind of information in your question. Try reflection.

Comment: *"In my case, Class A is already exists"* - Then the question is, why do you want to access to a field in a class where access has not been provided?

Comment: Don't hide vital information in a) code-comments or b) post-comments. Add all details that are actually complicating your issue to the post itself by using the "edit" feature.

Comment: Ok I will tyr reflection

Comment: Be a man. Inject a getter with ASM.

Answer (score 2):

[Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) will allow you to access the fields of existing classes.

**WARNING**: This is a *very* bad practice, and you should attempt to explore all possible avenues before embarking on this path.  This could *severely* compromise the functionality of the class you are accessing.  You have to ask your self, *"why is this field private?"*

```
public class TestReflection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestReflection();
    }

    public TestReflection() {

        PrivateAccessOnly instance = new PrivateAccessOnly();

        try {
            Field field = PrivateAccessOnly.class.getDeclaredField("field");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            System.out.println("Current value = " + field.get(instance));
            field.set(instance, new JButton("Testing"));
            System.out.println("New value = " + field.get(instance));
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public class PrivateAccessOnly {

        private JButton field;

    }
}
```

Comment: Really, just *why?* is sufficient. ;)

Comment: +1 for caveats; copyedited, but resisted adding [`☠`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2620/index.htm).

Comment: @J.Steen You should take a look at the code for `JDialog` sometime, I got much of the idea from there ;) - But agree, *why?* is enough in most cases

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for the udpates, 9 month old, teething and not wanting to go to sleep - make daddy very, something, something...

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that you will need to consider.

1. Instance of class A should be accessible to class B, OR instance of class B should be able to create instance of class A.
2. Create instance of button in class A.
3. Write "getter" method in class A which will return instance of button in A (Remember here, you must complete step 2 before this. If you do not create of instance of button in class A, you will return null from getter method and it will result in NullPointerException).
4. Call this getter method from instance of class B.
5. Add action listener on button object returned by getter method.

Comment: //Note :: newBTN  is not added and not initialized.

Comment: If newBTN is not initialized, then you will end up returning null from getter method in class A. As said in answer, you will get NullPointerException then. Can you tell us where you would like to initialize your newBTN?

Comment: You may have missed this *"Class A is already exst. I cannot change the code in Class A"* in the comments :P, otherwise a good answer